# JavaScript error when function called in JavaScript, not when called in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I had an idea to let the computer guess the number with JavaScript as code language. I know exactly what it must do, but it isn't doing it. The idea is (to see if it works) to get a random number between 1 and 100, when you open the webpage. Weird thing, is that if I call the function in the same JavaScript file it gives an error, but if I call the function with a HTML button, it's working totally fine! The F12-console gives the following error:

**Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference**

I have the following code:

```js
var guessTheNumber = function() {

// var number = prompt("Tell me a number between 1 and 100.");
var x = document.getElementById("JS1");

x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}


guessTheNumber();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>JS test</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="guessTheNumber()"></button>
 <p class="test">test</p>
 <p id="JS1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome as browsers, no results. I do not know what I am doing wrong, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yous js call is done before the dom is ready

Comment: okay and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the javascript file is loaded **BEFORE** the DOM, so the `document.getElementById("JS1");` would be undefined.

To easily fix this, load the `<script>` at the BOTTOM of the `<body>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS test</title>


</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="guessTheNumber()"></button>
    <p class="test">test</p>
    <p id="JS1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Though generally script at bottom of body is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
// self executing function here
var guessTheNumber = function() {

    // var number = prompt("Tell me a number between 1 and 100.");
    var x = document.getElementById("JS1");

    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
(function() {

   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
   guessTheNumber();
})();
</script>
```

You have to wait until the dom is ready.

Also never declare your script in the `head` move your script tag below `body`.

Comment: What was the problem, and how does this fix it?

Comment: What do you mean `no result`?

Comment: The problem is that $ is then undefined, which stops the whole code from running.

Comment: Using jquery is overkill for this example

Comment: @BrentMeeusen It's undefined because you have this script in the head, and needs to be below body. Coupled with the document ready function I have here. I updated my answer.

Comment: @SeeDart Touche. Removed jQuery.

Comment: Thank you! The jQuery way of waiting for the document to load did not work, but moving the link to the body did what it had to do!

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't have jQuery, so now it's just using javascript pure, you should wait until dom is ready anyways, good practice.

Comment: is it for a jQuery library and jQuery document also important to call them at the bottom of the body?

Comment: @BrentMeeusen Whether jQuery or not, yes. Always make sure your scripts are below body.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this (without jQuery):

```
var guessTheNumber = function() {

    // var number = prompt("Tell me a number between 1 and 100.");
    var x = document.getElementById("JS1");

    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    guessTheNumber();
}, false);
```